# What is the mathematical description of "training" in supervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, definition

What are we trying to achieve mathematically when we "train" a model in the context of supervised learning?

I have never seen a mathematical description of training in the context of supervised learning.

I propose the following crude description,

> Given a dataset $D = \{(x_n, y_n)\}, x_n \in \mathcal{X}, y_n \in \mathcal{Y}, \forall n$, we split the dataset into a
> training set $D_{tr}$ and a test set $D_{ts}$. Then to "train a model" is adjust the parameter $w$ of a function $M(x; w): \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ such that $M(x;w)$ achieves good
> performance on the training set $D_{tr}$ , and good performance on the test set $D_{ts}$.

I am surprised at how vague of a definition I came up with...for example, how is the set splitted? What about validation set? What does it mean by good performance? I'm troubled by the fact I cannot describe this problem mathematically. I am wondering if I am solving the correct problem all along.

Now an alternative way is to describe the process of training as loss minimization. However, the problem here is that how do I capture generalization? Minimizing the loss simply captures the portion where I am training to achieve good performance on the training set $D_{tr}$, but no guarantee that I will achieve good performance on the test set $D_{ts}$.

Does anyone know how I could make my description better?

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the data is not part of model fitting; it is part of model validation. Using linear regression as a motivating example, supervised learning (mathematically formulated) is an optimization problem.  We seek $\hat{\beta}$ such that our given loss $\mathcal{L}$ is minimized.

$$ \hat{\beta} = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p}{\operatorname{argmin}}\left\{  \mathcal{L}(\beta;\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{y}) \right\} $$

Here, $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now, this is only for linear regression. For other supervised algorithms, different formulations would be required.  Unless you're searching for a more general formulation.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi thanks. The thing is that speaking as a human, often our goal for training is to develop a model that makes prediction outside of the training set we are given. How do we capture this notion that we want a good fit on our dataset, but we also want good predictions on things that are outside of the dataset?

Comment: Implicit in this formulation is that the learned model will generalize to new observations.  It is difficult to formulate the task of predicting new data sufficiently well because *those data are unknown at prediction time*.